# D3 date parsing: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand [datetime parsing](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) in D3.js.

Why isn't the following working? It keeps giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Object 2012-06-01 12:00:00+0000 has no method 'getFullYear`.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%Z");
var datestr = '2012-06-01 12:00:00+0000';

console.log('d.datestr', datestr, typeof datestr);
console.log(parseDate(datestr));
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EBj9Z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

To parse a date, you need to use [format.parse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format):

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
format.parse("2011-01-01"); // returns a Date
format(new Date(2011, 0, 1)); // returns a string
```

[Additionally](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse):

> The %Z directive (time zone offset, such as "-0700") is not yet supported for parsing.